# Cannot post data with jQuery Form Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have the following code (works fine) that i want to change it into jQuery Form Plugin ajaxForm() :

```
$("#replysubmit").click(function() {
    var msg = $("#message").val();
    var attach = $("#attach").val();
    var id = $("input[name=hidden-ticketID]").val();
    if(msg == "") {
            alert("not null");
            $("#message").focus();
            return false;
        }
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/TicketSystem/support/view',
        async: false,
        data: {id: id, msg: msg, attach: attach},
        success: function(json) {
            $.post('/TicketSystem/support/ajaxmsg', { date: json.date, msg: json.msg }, 
            function(data){
                var newData = $('<div>').addClass('msgBlock').html(data).hide();
                newData.appendTo($('.msgWrapper')).slideDown('normal');
                goToByScroll('reply-form');
            });
            $("#message").val('');
            $("#attach").val('');
        }
    });
    return false;});
```

and this is the ajaxForm() i wrote :

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
var msg = $("#message").val();
var attach = $("#attach").val();
var id = $("input[name=hidden-ticketID]").val();
var options = { 
    //target:        '#output1',   // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
    beforeSubmit:  showRequest,  // pre-submit callback 
    success:       showResponse,  // post-submit callback 

    // other available options: 
    url: '/TicketSystem/support/view',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {id: id, msg: msg, attach: attach},
    //clearForm: true        // clear all form fields after successful submit 
    //resetForm: true        // reset the form after successful submit 

    // $.ajax options can be used here too, for example: 
    //timeout:   3000 
}; 

// bind form using 'ajaxForm' 
$('#user-reply-form').ajaxForm(options); });
```

The post data from the ajaxForm are wierd... and my php code couldnt receive anything from it except the file upload now works.

Comment: try using `$('#user-reply-form').ajaxSubmit(options);`

Comment: -----------------------------16737309517074 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="message" zxc

Comment: no idea what you just posted

Comment: -----------------------------16737309517074 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="message" zxc
   -----------------------------16737309517074 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="msg"
                 The actual data is in that name="message" instead of "msg" which is what my server-side code looking for, can i change this behavior somehow?

Comment: since submitting a form remove the `data` option... assume all fields you want are in the form. Otherwise post a lot more specifics about what you need and what is or isn't working

Comment: thanks alot i got it works now. although: id=1016&msg=hello&attach= is what my php code were looking for from what is posted, i had to change 'msg' to 'message' and vice versa for other pararms, can i change it in a way that it posts 'msg' instead of 'message'? Also 'message' is the element's name so i guess the form use those name to post instead of what in the data:{} object.

Comment: can change `name` of inputs, can also use `$.ajaxPrefilter` to modify data